# aligned environment of amsmath vs array environment

Tags: amsmath, align, arrays

Today I found out the existence of the `aligned` environment of the `amsmath` package. However, I can't see the advantage of using it instead of the `array` environment from the example provided in amsldoc.pdf, Sec.3.7. In particular, as I can just get almost the same result by using the `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \left.\begin{aligned}
        B'&=-\partial\times E,\\
        E'&=\partial\times B - 4\pi j, 
    \end{aligned}
    \right\}
    \qquad \text{Maxwell’s equations}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \left.\begin{array}{l}
        B'=-\partial\times E,\\
        E'=\partial\times B - 4\pi j, 
    \end{array}
    \right\}
    \qquad \text{Maxwell’s equations}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

giving the output

[image]

What are the differences, and why should one be preferred over the other in this context?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`aligned` basically gives you a sequence of `r@{}l` column pairs; thus there is no spacing between the two columns in a pair. However, a trick adjusts things so that `x&=y` gives the right spacing around the equals sign, or any other relation symbol, which is where usually alignment points are desired.

Some control is made so that lines aren't vertically too near, which isn't done in `array`. Here's a visual comparison. Note what must be done differently in `array`: one has to add `{}` before the `=` and use `\dfrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\!\begin{aligned}
a&=bbb & c&=\frac{x}{y} \\
aa&=bbbb & cc&=\frac{x}{y}
\end{aligned}
\]
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}l@{\quad}@{}r@{}l@{}}
a&{}=bbb & c&{}=\dfrac{x}{y} \\
aa&{}=bbbb & cc&{}=\dfrac{x}{y}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

(The `\!` is due to a glitch in `amsmath` that is kept for historical reasons; however it doesn't hurt much if no comparison has to be made. Newer versions of `amsmath` don't need it.)

[image]

In conclusion, `array` and `aligned` are different tools, each one has its pros and cons, depending on the problem that has to be solved: `array` is more flexible in terms of horizontal alignment of cells, `aligned` has other features that make it preferable in some situations. Don't forget `alignedat`, that allows to specify the horizontal space between column pairs.

Also to be noticed is that `align` and `alignat` have no `array` counterpart: with `array` one can't number lines (easily, at least).

Comment: So if I do not write the ``\!``, an equation with width of linewidth issues a warning (and maybe sticks out to the right that amount)?

Comment: @jjdb A thin space is added (1/6 of a em, so it shouldn't really be a concern).

Comment: Ok, but in two-column articles one has often to fight to get the equation into one line. I encountered a few times the situation where adding a \! somewhere command made the black boxes from the draft mode vanish

Comment: How does one number the lines with ``aligned``? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @egreg Can you add information on the best practice for choosing either using `array` or `aligned`? I was just wondering again which one I should use.

Comment: @Zelphir `array` is for, well, arrays; for aligning different equations, `aligned` or similar environments are better.

Comment: @egreg Ok `aligned` is clear for me then, but `array` is not so clear for me. When would you use `array` instead of some `matrix` then? Isn't an array a matrix? I don't know how to distinguish those yet. In mathematics itself I've never heard of arrays, only of matrices so far. However, I didn't study mathematics, might be I am missing something.

Comment: @Zelphir You're right: matrices are built with `array` (but it's better to use the appropriate `amsmath` special environments); `array` is more general and can come handy in case some complex alignment is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Note that in your example you have not used an alignment point `&` The `=` are aligned just because `B` and `E` happen to have the same width. If you changed your example, for example used `W` or a different expression altogether then you would have to work a bit harder to get the correct spacing around `=`.

Comment: Is this a typo in your answer as this question is  about the ``aligned`` environment, not about the  ``align`` environment.

Comment: @jjdb I can't reconstruct my thought process: I'll delete the last sentence, thanks:-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one, notice the difference in spacing and the squeezing of the two lines. I am not aware of the internal mechanism that distinguishes the two, but in terms of usage, aligned is far simpler and easier, allows me to focus on the equation rather than array elements. A similar difference can be noticed in the matrix environments bmatrix, pmatrix, and vmatrix in amsmath vs creation of such matrices manually using various brackets and the array environment.