# What all those @{} resp @{\quad} in preamble of this array mean?

Tags: arrays

as I was reading different question [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111891/aligned-environment-of-amsmath-vs-array-environment) I've found code of array enviroment which preamble is quite unknown to be... I see what it does but I would like to understand it to be able use that technique for different situations... I understand what "`c`" "`l`" "`r`" mean but not the rest:

```
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}l@{\quad}@{}r@{}l@{}}
a&{}=bbb & c&{}=\dfrac{x}{y} \\
aa&{}=bbbb & cc&{}=\dfrac{x}{y}
\end{array}
\]
```

I was trying to apply it in such a form that I have just one centered column and then right and left which are aligned according to = inside so I wrote 
`\begin{array}{c@{\quad}@{}r@{}l@{}}` and something inside environment according to example above but it gave me an error in a form that there are unknown characters in preamble of array... so obviously I do not understand those "`@{}`"resp "`@{\quad}`" parts and I wasn't able to find satisfactory answer on the web...

Comment: The only error I get is caused by `\dfrac` not being defined - you need to load `amsmath` for that function.  The `@{...}` constructions kill the intercolumn space and replace it with whatever is between the curly braces.

Comment: I did not show complete code I just wanted to know meaning of those characters...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 21):

On either side of each column of an `array` (or `tabular`) latex adds `\arraycolsep`) (or `\tabcolsep` for `tabular`) of whitespace, so normally there is `2\arraycolsep` space between the columns.

If you go `@{hello}` then *instead* of adding space between the columns latex inserts `hello` in each row.

Sometimes you see forms such as `r@{\mbox{--}}l`  which would make `2 & 3` appear as 2–3

The most common form though is `@{}` which doesn't add anything but removes the inter column space.

`\quad` is short for `\hspace{1em}` so `@{\quad}` changes the inter-column space from `2\arraycolsep` (which is usually 10pt) to `1em` (which is usually 10pt).

Comment: And that {} inside of array after & sign is also used for removing spaces?

Comment: @JozefJanočko adding them actually. Compare `$=1$` and `${}=1$` with the first form `=` is at the start so loses its infix relation spacing , here you want it to look like infix even though it is at the start of the cell so `{}` is added.

Comment: @Mico thanks, fixed, had an "interesting" effect on the last sentence:-)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the formal references that mentions this notation in the preamble construction of `tabular` or `array`:

- [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **56.2 `array` and `tabular` environments**, p 300)

  The PREAMBLE argument of an `array` or `tabular` environment can
  contain the following:

  - `l`,`r`,`c` : indicate where entry is to be placed.
  - `|` : for vertical rule
  - `@{EXP}` : inserts the text `EXP` in every column.
    `\arraycolsep` or `\tabcolsep` spacing is suppressed.
  - `*{N}{PRE}` : equivalent to writing `N` copies of `PRE` in the preamble.
    `PRE` may contain `*{N’}{EXP’}` expressions.
  - `p{LEN}` : makes entry in `\parbox` of width `LEN`.

It's also mentioned in Table 1 (p 2) of the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf).

`@{<stuff>}` suppresses the inter-column separation and uses `<stuff>` instead.

Answer (score 7):

David Carlisle has already given a thorough answer as to what `@{}` and `@{\quad}` do. I'd like to add an observation regarding how the code for the `array` could have been set up more elegantly in the first place, in a way that would have avoided the need for the five [5!] instances of the `@{}` directive.

Specifically, by inserting the instruction `\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}` immediately after `\[`, all five instances of `@{}` could have been avoided, streamlining the code that sets up the structure of the `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\dfrac" macro
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % default value: 5pt
  \begin{array}{rl @{\quad} rl}
     a&{}=bbb  &  c&{}=\dfrac{x}{y} \\[3ex]
    aa&{}=bbbb & cc&{}=\dfrac{x}{y}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```