# Star notation in array preamble flawed?

Tags: arrays

According to section 56.2 of the [LaTeX2e sources](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (which is summarized [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288067/what-all-those-resp-quad-in-preamble-of-this-array-mean#answer-288107)), it is possible to use the syntax *{N}{x} to specify xx...x (N times) in the preamble of an array.

I would like to be able to use *{0}{l}. I'm concerned with the fact that the following two pieces of code do not behave the same:

```
\[\begin{array}{*{0}{l} *{2}{l}}
  a & b
\end{array}\]

\[\begin{array}{*{2}{l} *{0}{l}}
  a & b
\end{array}\]
```

I'm able to compile the second array but not the first (pdflatex complains about a missing # inserted in alignment preamble).

Is there anything I need to be aware of? As far as I can see, there is no mention of the case N=0 in the documentation, and nothing is said about the first use of the star notation in an array preamble.

If this is a bug in the LaTeX2e implementation, who should I warn?

Comment: Mmh maybe my LaTeX distribution is faulty then, would you mind telling me if you also use TeX Live 2014?

Comment: Try to load the `array` package, i.e. `\usepackage{array}`

Comment: @StefanH, this works, but as I'm writing a package myself, I would prefer not to rely on another package whereas it seems unnecessary for some users ... I'm currently updating my distribution to TeX Live 2015, but if this is a requirement, I would like to be aware of it to at least notify it in the documentation ... Do you think adding array as a package requirement is an acceptable solution?

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid I didn't the documentation up to page 312 :p Thanks for pointing this out, I'll just add `array` as a package requirement then :-) Thank you for your help ! @campa I will accept your answer if you post it

Comment: @FabianPijcke: If you don't want to rely on another package, then copy the necessary package code into yours and use it.

Comment: From the documentation of `array.sty` it seems you need version 2.1 or later. I don't know when this is in time, but the latest version seems to be 2.4d from October 2016. You can specify it in your `sty`-file as `\RequirePackage[<options>]{array}[<version>]` but then I think `<version>` is the date of the version.

Comment: Considering that `array` has status as a [required](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/required) package, relying on it is probably fine.

Comment: @FabianPijcke As noted `array` is _absolutely required_ as part of a LaTeX installation and is therefore assume to be available by the standard documentation.

Comment: I didn't know of that list of required packages. Very useful indeed. I'll just add it as a dependency. Thank you all again!

Comment: Sorry but for what do you need to insert a type declaration for zero columns? Is this for ghost values?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, No, this is for a command generating tables that are made of two parts, each of which may be empty. The command has the form `\tbl{leftpartheader}{rightpartheader}{values}` where each partheader is a (possibly empty) sequence of names and values is a semicolon-separated sequence of comma-separated tuples.

Answer (score 4):

This is more or less documented in the `array` package documentation (comparing actually against an earlier version of the package rather than against the version in the format), but it says

> % \subsection{Comparisons with older versions of `array.sty`}
>
> ...
>
> % \item A preamble of the form `{wx*{0}{abc}yz}` was treated by
>
> % versions prior to 2.1 as `{wx}`. Version 2.1 treats it as `{wxyz}`